# Bool reported as undefined. When typedef added; error that Bool is already defined

Tags: c

I'm writing embedded software for the ti C5515 in ccstudio, using the CSL libraries. I'm having trouble with type definitions. In specific, I get this error:

```
#20 identifier "Bool" is undefined  in csl_intc.h
```

Taking a look at the header, I find the bool definition in tistdtypes.h; within scope, as far as I can tell. In desperation, I add a typedef to the top of the file. However, then it complains that bool is already defined.

I've made sure that the case is the same, and that there isn't another tistdtypes.h somewhere overriding the definition. How is it possible that it complains that there is no typedef, but when I add one, it says that there is one already?

Here are the two errors, one after the other:

```
#20 identifier "Bool" is undefined  TMS320C5515     line 992, external location: ... csl_intc.h 
#102 "Bool" has already been declared in the current scope  TMS320C5515     line 914, external location: ... csl_intc.h
```

The file path is exactly the same. I can also paste the lines between 992 and 914 if necessary. There isn't much.

Comment: Could you provide some source code where this is being included, used, and the make file/command to build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I use the [file in question](http://rejointech.googlecode.com/svn-history/r6/trunk/csl/tistdtypes.h):

```
#include "tistdtypes.h"

int main(){
    Bool something = 0;
```

and run this program via `gcc -Werror -Wall`, I'm not seeing any such errors. So unless your version is different from the one I linked to, I'd say there's something wrong with how it's being compiled into your program.

Could you add some more details regarding how it's included, if your version of `tistdtypes.h` is different than when I linked to, and how the target is being compiled?

As a "worst case" backup at least you know that a `Bool` is really a `unsigned short`, so you could always modify your code to just not use the typedef.

**EDIT:**
I just took a look at [csl_intc.h](http://rejointech.googlecode.com/svn-history/r6/trunk/csl/csl_intc.h). It uses `Bool` in that file without including the definition of it. What happens if you include `tistdtypes.h` in this file?

Comment: That csl_intc.h isn't the one I have. The one I have includes <csl_types.h> which contains <tistdtypes.h>. Interestingly enough, even <csl_types.h> complains that it doesn't know what a bool is.

I've managed to fix the problem by removing a set of propriety libraries I added to my code a few days ago. These libraries also have a Bool definition, although my understanding that the scopes were completely separate. Perhaps not? I did check that the #ifndef_TI_STD_TYPES wrappers were not duplicated in the proprietry libraries (on some off chance).

Answer (score 1):

There is a `#ifndef STD_` around the definition. Do you know what defines are passed by your compiler/other includes ?

One way to find out it to turn up the verbosity of the preprocessor to see all the code which is parsed. Maybe that will give you some insight why that is being skipped.

With gcc that would be `gcc -E` to stop after preprocessing and dump the parsed content. You might want to find the option for your compiler if you use a different one.